# Cannot create Azure Service Project Package using Azure CmdLets

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I have a cloud service project in VS 2013 RTM.

I use **Save-AzureServiceProjectPackage -Local** command to generate CSPKG package. I am getting following error. Not sure why. Can anybody help.

[image]

Here is my Cloud CSCFG File -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="WindowsAzure1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2013-10.2.2">
  <Role name="WebRole1">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

And here is my Service Definition CSDEF file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="WindowsAzure1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2013-10.2.2">
  <WebRole name="WebRole1" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Windows Azure PowerShell doesn't support packaging VS projects. The new version which will be early December 2013 will have this support.

Comment: Assuming you're trying to package a cloud project created by Visual Studio (not sure why you would want to do that with PowerShell when you have Visual Studio and other utilities available), take a look here: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/issues/1614.

In short, this Cmdlet is not intended to package VS projects as mentioned above.

Comment: My idea is to have a project folder with all default files. This structure I want to use it as TEMPLATE. Then re-use this template to create custom solutions by replacing/overriding necessary files and then package it. Everything needs to be on the fly. So I cannot go to Visual Studio packaging option (which is manual). Anyways I solved the problem by using CSPACK.

Comment: version 0.7.2 have this change but it's not released yet, feel free to get the bits from dev branch and they them yourself.